# Latex using Uninstalled Font

Tags: latex, xelatex

I was using `Open Sans Condensed` as font for my Latex documents. Here is what I did:

```
\setprimaryfont{Open Sans Condensed Light}
```

After that, I uninstalled `Open Sans Condensed` but when I create a document, Latex still uses this font.

How can I get rid of any Latex Cache that allows it to use an uninstalled font?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you uninstall the font? Can you show your .log file? (I suspect there is still a version of the font installed somewhere on your system)

Comment: [are you sure you mean `\setprimaryfont` and not, say, `\setmainfont`?]

Comment: Yes @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz :). I am using amsmath package as well. :)

Comment: Does MikTex install Open Sans Condensed by default?

Comment: With `\setmainfont` from fontspec, you are using fonts from your system. You need to uninstall them via your operating system. This has nothing to do with what miktex install or not. To see where the font comes from, we would need to see your .log file

Comment: Thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Where would the log file be located?

Comment: The log file is normally in the same folder as your .tex file